# Error logs while signing using Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, ios9, xcode7

I am getting following error when trying to login via FB
I am using FB sdks 4.8.0

Error log :

> -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "(null)"

Answer (score 1):

**The error you see in the console is normal. You will see this when calling canOpenURL and the corresponding app isn't not installed. The error can be safely ignored.**

For same question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958000/facebook-login-error-in-ios9

Also Set your info.plist as per image

[image]